# Is there a proper term for the "path" to an html element?

Tags: html, css

I am talking about the all the nodes between the HTML tag and the node you are looking for. From another perspective, it's a recursive list of all the parents of the node.

Say you have something like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a>
            <b>
                <em>
                    <p></p>
                </em>
            </b>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then the "path" to `<p>` is `html > body > a > b > em > p` using CSS selectors.

Comment: You could use node's hierarchy to mean a node and all its parents

Comment: I've always heard it referred to as a path. If you right click an element in Chrome Dev tools it gives you two options to get a path, there's "CSS Path" and "XPath". According to that I'd call it a "CSS Path", though.

Answer (score 1):

Officially, that's called an 'XPath' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

More commonly, the elements are referred to as "ancestors" or "descendants" of the target, or 'current', element.  jQuery's documentation is a great example of this, talking a lot about 'traversing the DOM tree' looking for 'ancestors' or 'descendants' (http://api.jquery.com/find/).